# CMD/PowerShell - Save File As XML

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a pretty basic question.
I have a txt file and I want to convert it into a xml file.
So usually I would just use "rename 'text file' 'xml file' as a command, and the result is a xml file.

But the problem is => This doesnt work, my code (which is based on a software I use and only changebale to a certain degree - but not enough to avoid the problem) can't read the xml and it still recognizes it as a txt file (even though it is clearly a xml file).

The only way it works is as follows (manually):

Opening the txt file in the editor, go to file => save as => save as type: All files => renaming the file to file.xml and save it.
This sounds ridiculous, but it is the only way my code can read the xml file.

So my question is: 
How can I implement the solution above into a cmd or Powershell line?

Because "rename 'text file' 'xml file' " or "ren *txt *xml" does not work, even though the result is clearly a xml file. But if there would be a way where I can implement the solution above into a cmd line it would work perfect.
Thank you very much!

Edit:
It seems that this may be an encoding problem, is there a way to change it from Unicode to ANSI?

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add the code that reads the XML. Add sample .txt file contents too. While you are at it, add a description about what happens when your program tries in vain to read the file. Is there an error message? What does it say? Something else is wrong, what?

Comment: The problem with the code is that it is based on the software I use in the background, so changing the code is only possible to a certain degree, but not enough to avoid the problem. In my case it would be enough if I could call the right cmd or powershell before it even reads the txt/xml file. And if there is a way where a cmd or powershell command could reproduce the solution which I described.

Comment: This might be an encoding problem. Without seeing actual data or error messages, it's just a wild guess.

Comment: @vonPryz It seems that you are right, it looks like it is an encoding problem, is there a way to change it from Unicode to ANSI?

Comment: It often is, but the correct method depends on what's wrong with the file. I'm pretty sure you've run into BOM issues, but it can be something else too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below PowerShell command. Demo.txt is a txt demo file and Demo.xml will get created in same folder.

`Get-Content Demo.txt | Set-Content Demo.xml`